# Automatically Setting Internet Explorer/Windows to use a Socks5 proxy using C#

Tags: c#, http, sockets

I'm making a SSH Tunnelling application, and need to be able to automatically force the system to use HTTP & Socks5 proxies, and have the changes take effect instantly.
HTTP proxies are now taken care of perfectly by the [PoshHTTP class](http://huddledmasses.org/setting-windows-internet-connection-proxy-from-c/) , but I can't figure out how to do the same with SOCKS5.

I've already tried forcing the changes in the registry, but they don't take effect instantly and it's just not reliable. In most cases I had to open internet options > lan settings before the settings would take effect, so the user may as well have set the proxy up manually by this point.

Is there a way to do this that I'm missing ? It would be amazing if I could just modify poshHTTP to do this, but I don't have high hopes.

Comment: Is it really necessary to change the proxy settings for the whole machine if you only really need it in your SSH tunnel application? What are you using to perform the tunneling?

Comment: Yes, as many applications as possible should be automatically configured to use the newly created tunnel. The app itself is just using a geolookup api with a standard webrequest (taking ie settings) to confirm that traffic is being tunnelled. 

I'm using a Plink base for the tunnelling at the moment, but I'm looking to move to an internal library for ssh functions and removing the plink dependancy ASAP. But this is a seperate issue :P

Comment: Also, I already had a question created here with no response - so I made the one in the programming subforum that was then moved here. Sorry if this is against the rules to doublepost, I just really need an answer ASAP.. and by moving theres now 3 seperate posts on the same topic instead of 2 ..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832641/setting-internet-explorer-windows-to-use-a-socks5-proxy-in-c-sharp

Comment: Volunteers typically don't respond well to *ASAP*. If you're looking for quick response time try paying someone to help you. That said I still see yet why you need to overwrite the machine's proxy settings. This just feels like bad juju. If you have multiple applications that should use the same proxy then they should implement the proxy individually. Even if it doesn't seem valid, it is only a matter of time until the box gets purposed for a different reason and suddenly none of the new application's connections work.

Comment: The whole point of the application is to be able to quickly and easily connect to an SSH server, and have the system configured to use the new tunnel. When the tunnel goes down, settings are removed immediately.

I understand what you're saying about the ASAP, but it would be very difficult to find someone with the specific knowledge needed for what I'm trying to achieve so I'm posting publicl to an audience that might be able to help.

Hell, I'll even pay someone $50USD to give me an answer on here.

Comment: My point is what I'm trying to do exactly is in my original question, and while I appreciate that you're trying to help you do not understand the context around what I'm trying to do. I would be appreciative if the question could be answered, or say nothing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution after asking for help on another forum.
In the end I was able to continue to use the PoshHTTP class I used elsewhere but instead of passing just ip:port use it like this

```
PoshHttp.Proxies.SetProxy("socks=socks://$ip:$port");
```

Answer (score 1):

Anyone came here wondering about Tor, this may be useful to you

```
    public struct Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO
    {
        public int dwAccessType;
        public IntPtr proxy;
        public IntPtr proxyBypass;
    };

    [DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, int dwOption, IntPtr lpBuffer, int lpdwBufferLength);

    public static void RefreshProxy()
    {
        try
        {
            //RESTART TOR
            Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO struct_IPI;
            struct_IPI.dwAccessType = 3;
            struct_IPI.proxy = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("socks=127.0.0.1:9050");
            struct_IPI.proxyBypass = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("local");
            IntPtr intptrStruct = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(struct_IPI, intptrStruct, true);
            InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, 38, intptrStruct, Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI));
        }
        catch (Exception){ }
    }
```